# Export Access '95 Table to Excel

Tags: ms-access

I have a VERY old Access 95 userform that performs all sorts of functions. What I need to do is export one table to Excel or even to a text file. I have found a couple of lines of code in my search but nothing has worked. I'm guessing due to it being Access 95.  Does anyone know how I can do this? I want to export the table on Form Open.  Thanks for any help!

Comment: You can open an Access 95 file with a much newer version of Access where the usual export commands will work properly. You can probably even link the table to a newer Access file.

Comment: Are there no commands to do this in Access 95?

Comment: My first Access project was in Access 2000 so I would not know any more than whatever google can tell you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet` and `DoCmd.TransferText` were available in Access 95. Are you actually *running* your database with Access 95?

Comment: The database is running Access 95. The only reason I have not converted it is because the conversion fails and says VB is corrupt.

Comment: VB is corrupt or VB doesn't build? Can you compile while in the IDE?